# Is it possible to use a button with text for the jquery mobile split button list?

Tags: jquery, button, mobile, split

JQuery Mobile uses the icon for the actions in the right column when in split button list: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-split.html. I need to display a full size button with text and icon for the right column. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with this for ages...

I can't see how it's easily done - maybe someone else will.

For a hack, though, since the whole right hand side of a split list is a link, why don't you make it wider with css, and put an image into it that looks like a button, CSSing to change it on :hover?

I know it's not ideal, but it might just work.

Sorry can't give you a more adaptable solution!

Comment: It's harder than I thought, but your suggestion will work for now. Thanks! Still hope there will be a better hack.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed static text next to the button. I was able to do this all using CSS2+.  No javascript needed.  Hope this helps someone.

CSS:

```
.split-icon-link {
width: 116px !important;
}

 .split-icon-link > .ui-btn-inner:before {
float: left;
font-size: 15px;
padding: .7em 4px;
content: "View Store"; /*this is the text to display*/
}
```

HTML:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="home"
 data-split-theme="d">
        <li>
            <a href="#yoururl">
                <span>The big button text</span>
            </a>
            <a class="split-icon-link" href="#splitbututoniconurl"></a>
        </li>
  </ul>
```